# Mysql returns 0 rows affected for Multiple data insert

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

[image: This is what i am asking 0 Rows affected even after successful execution of store procedure]I am using c# application with mysql db

but even when i execute procedure from mysql workbench terminal i am getting 0 rows affected but Data gets inserted (Confirmed with table after procedure execution)

- One is master table
- One is transaction table

Ex:-
Store Procedure Execution

- Insert record in master table  - 1 row
- Insert record in transaction table - 2 row

but still i get 0 rows affected

I have tried in other store procedure where only data gets inserted in master table (1 row) but where i get result 1 row affected

Can you please find me correct solution ?

Procedure Call:-

```
 INSERT INTO A(Id,CreationTime,CreatorId,Name,
                                                            IsDeleted)
            VALUES(@iId ,current_timestamp() ,iCurrentUserId,iGroupName ,0); 
                        
    SET @iUsers = Concat("'",REPLACE(iUsers,",","','"),"'");
        
    SET @SqlText = CONCAT('INSERT INTO B(Id,AId,UserId)
                            Select uuid(),@iId ,Id
                            FROM   Users
                            where   ID IN (',@iUsers,')');
                 
                    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQLText;
                    EXECUTE stmt;
                    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Based on result i am returning response in c# , so rather than changing all store procedure by passing out parameter i want to find exact solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide some code. Are we supposed to guess what you are doing?

Comment: The procedure itself (you execute a procedure) does not affect any record. The queries in the procedure do it - but this information is received (and is dead immediately) in the procedure, during its execution. If you want to see the amount of affected rows out of the procedure then you must in the procedure's body query ROW_COUNT() after each data-altering query execution summarize (or concatenate, or gather by another way) the amount of affected rows, and return this information by any way (SELECT, UDV, OUT).

Comment: @Akina Thanks for your help but when you use IN subquery to insert multiple records then how you can achieve it , and i don't want number like how many rows affected my main purpose is i am considering if i get correct value then i can return valid message (message depends on value return by execution of store procedure)

Comment: [DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=974eaa6deb3ee4fa335ff870f9767cb6). You may collect the info for a lot of queries in one variable (concatenate, gather in JSON array, etc.) quering the info after each modifying query in SP.

Comment: @Akina you have used out variable for me that is way of changing lots of implementation. if you can see my code and let me know when data is getting inserted correctly why it is returning 0 rows affected as message (I don't want to see that outside procedure). Thanks for help

Comment: I have used THREE different methods. I show that EACH gives correct output. Of course it's enough to use any one of them.

Comment: @Akina Can you check same link ? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2381fdb0d3d43816454b21135d4b30b1 i updated code , inserting in two table doesn't work

Comment: Always check your code for syntax validity. You forget to specify datatypes for `test1` columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224465/discussion-between-viken-patel-and-akina).

Comment: Does table have a primary key?  You can have only one entry in database with the key.  So Insert will not work and you need to use Update.

Comment: @jdweng yes both tables have primary key

Comment: when you have a primary key you ,must always test the return value.  An update will return zero if the key doesn't exist and then you have to use insert.  If you do an insert and the key exist you will get zero and then you  need to do update.

Comment: @Akina and jdweng please find attached screenshot, it gets successfully executed but returns 0 rows affected

Comment: @jdweng can you find screenshot and let me know ? or if any one can give exact solution

Comment: Where is c# code?

Comment: @jdweng it is returning even if i call procedure from mysql, in c# simple it is returning 0 rather than it should return 1

Comment: @DaveTheRave have you got solution for executing query using  EXECUTE stmt; in store procedure ? i am getting 0 rows affected

Comment: Try a Select and see if you get results :   Select *  from Users where   ID = @iUsers;